# Django Template filtering

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a website where you can view different "ranks" and the people within them. I have gotten it to create the ranks into there own Collapsable Panels, as I am using Bootstrap 3, but I am unable to list the Users who have that rank. Please help.

```
#team.html template
<div class="container">
 <div class="col-md-2">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    {% for rank in Rank_list %}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse{{rank.rank_num}}">
            {{ rank.rank_name }}s
          </a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse{{rank.rank_num}}" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
          {% for name in User_list %}
            <li>
              <p>{{name}}</p>
              </li>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
</div>
```

```
#views.py
class team(generic.ListView):
 template_name = 'main/team.html'
 context_object_name = 'Rank_list'
 context_object_name2 = 'User_list'

 def get_queryset(self):
    return Rank.objects.order_by('rank_num')
 def get_queryset2(self):
    return User.objects.order_by('name')

#models.py
class Rank(models.Model):
    rank_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rank_num = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.rank_name

class User(models.Model):
    rank = models.ForeignKey(Rank)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `related_name` to the foreign key. Like this:

```
rank = models.ForeignKey(Rank, related_name='users')
```

Then the users can be accessed in a loop like this:

```
{% for user in rank.users.all %}
   {{ user }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you! The helped out exactly as i needed!

Comment: No need to explicitly add a related_name. Django sets one by default, which would be `user_set`.

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark answer as accepted. Also, I recommend using Django's built in User model, as mentioned in comments below. See Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#user-objects

Answer (score 0):

For each `Rank` object, you can reverse the relationship and get all of the `Users` related to that `Rank`

```
# models.py
# - Use `related_name` for making relationship that are easy to read and follow
# - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name
class User(...):
    rank = models.ForeignKey(Rank, related_name="users")  

# view.py
# - Use prefetch_related allows us to cut down our queries when iterating as we do an up-front join
# - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related
...
def get_queryset(self):
    return Rank.objects.prefetch_related('users')('rank_num')  

# template.py
{% for rank in Rank_List %} # You shouldn't capitalise your template variables
    {% for user in rank.users.all %}  
        {{ user }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Finally, you should use the [built-in `User` model that django's `auth` module provides](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#user-objects)

Comment: I am using the built in User model as something else. Thanks though!